# Calling this.setState(); inside componentDidMount returns "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a google map component and I'm trying to set the lng and lat of the user into the state.

`position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` logs the right coordinates but when I try to set them into state I get the error in the title.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userLatitude: 0,
            userLongitude: 0
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude);

            this.setState({userLatitude: position.coords.latitude});
            this.setState({userLongitude: position.coords.longitude});
        });
    }
```

Comment: very common issue "context", use arrow function: `getCurrentPosition((position) => {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` the `getCurrentPosition` since this inside it doesn't refer to the React component's context and hence setState is unavailable

Also instead of using two `setState` statements, you should do it in one statement else your component will be re-rendered twice

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude);

        this.setState({userLatitude: position.coords.latitude, userLongitude: position.coords.longitude});
    });
```